# Changing the default SSH key path for IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: git, ssh, intellij-idea, ssh-keys

I'm using IntelliJ on a USB drive, so I'm trying to work out a portable install.
I've got most of everything to work, except for VCS.

Whenever I try to push some commits with Git, IntelliJ looks for an SSH key file, but it is looking in my home path (C:\Users\.ssh), and I would rather it looked for the SSH keys somewhere else (namely the IntelliJ IDEA installation folder on my USB drive)

So how can I change the directory where IntelliJ looks for SSH keys?
Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an [open feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-24944) for this in IntelliJ IDEA issue tracker, please vote,

Comment: Thank you for sharing that, I've now upvoted it. Though it seems unlikely to be patched soon as it's been over a year since the last update...

Answer (score 1):

IDEA uses `%HOME%` environment variable to search for `.ssh/known_hosts`. Setting it to different value might help. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26149790/1768278) for more details.

Comment: I did this and restarted my IntelliJ session with admin privileges and this fixed my issue with previous 'failed authentication(publickey)' error