# Android studio git using private key

Tags: git, android-studio, ssh, private-key

A have an address of git repository.
Also I have a private key in open-ssh format.
Is it possible for git in Android Studio to use it?
I tried to search some info, but no luck at this time.
Thanks for any useful information!

**Edit.** My steps:
1. I put my private key in .ssh folder (Users/user).
2. In Android studio I run: File - Settings - Version Control - Git and put the path to Git executable.
[image]
3. Then VCS - Checkout from vesrion control - Git. I put repository address there. [image]

If I continue here, there is:
[image]

But I don't have username and password, only key.
If I try:
[image]

 got the following:
[image]

**And how Android Studio would know, that it should take my private key instead of standard id_rsa file?**

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6746746/6131611

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ok, finally got it working!
What I did - switched to .ssh folder, then replaced contents of `id_rsa` key (as I understand, this is default ssh key of Android Studio) with contents of my `ssh key`.

Still don't know the way, how can I point Android Studio to my `ssh key`, but in such way it works.

Comment: That works! I can add, that the directory of that file is <user_directory>/.ssh. The appropriate ssh-key file starts with "Begin rsa private key".

Answer (score 19):

As @CodeWizard mentioned, Android Studio was getting the key from the OS so using ssh-add to add the keys to the ssh-agent worked for me.

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

More info:
https://help.github.com/en/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent

Comment: This answer only works on Linux and MacOS type systems. Windows does not have built-in ssh-agent support, and Android Studio does not work with PuTTY's Pageant authentication agent.

Answer (score 10):

How to get it working using Android Studio on Windows and PuttyGen for generating the key - for dummies:

1. Export your private key using PuttyGen to file Conversions>Export OpenSSHKey
2. On the Windows machine where you have Android Studio installed go to your %USERPROFILE%/.ssh directory.
3. Copy the file exported in step 1 to this folder and change filename to "id_rsa".
4. In Android Studio menu go to VCS>Checkout from Version Control>Git.
5. Paste Git url (as mentioned in other replies) and press "Clone".
6. It should ask you for password for the key file (if used) instead of a password for Git.

Answer (score 2):

To add one more answer.
Android Studio comes with Built in SSH client. You must switch from the built in to native.
This will use the keys from .ssh folder

File -> Settings -> Version Control -> Git -> SSH Executable -> Native

Comment: This actually allows using a GPG provided SSH key as well. This is especially handy if you are using a Yubikey hosted GPG key, since you have to unlock the GPG key using a PIN, which is then cached for a configurable period.

Comment: Be adviced that the configuration options for which SSH executable to use has been removed, and the native client is used now by default.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to add the key to your server.
Android studio is using the OS git and not Egit like in Eclipse which has its own git implementation.

No special configuration need to be done.
check that all is working from bash/terminal and it will work in the Android Studio as well.

---

### ***`What to do if its not working?`***

If you cant access your repository from the Studio use the following format as your connections url

```
:ssh:git@<server ip>:<git repository path>
```

This will use a direct connection using ssh keys.

Comment: Hmmm, thanks for your answer, but I still don't understand, what should I do. In A-Studio I do VCS - Checkout from version control - Git. But where should I place my private key, which I received? Also I don't know, how to make it work via git console (in Windows app).

Comment: You simply have to place the key under your %HOME%/.ssh in windows its Users/username

Comment: If I put only git address, it requires password for username, which shouldn't be. If I use your way with ssh:git@<server ip>:<git repository path>, got an error Clone failed: Could not read from remote repository.

Comment: Generate ssh keys and place them under your .ssh folder. it should work with no problems

Comment: Read it. What is the problem that to having now?

Comment: Put more screenshots. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you are using the wrong url. The url (before using ssh://) should be `git://...`

Comment: I put git://192....2:myRepo, it gives me "Clone failed: No path specified. See 'man git-pull' for valid url syntax"