# How to use local Git server on my raspberry with Android Studio?

Tags: android, windows, git, android-studio, server

I want to use my Git server which is on my Raspberry (Raspbian) in order to store and use versioning with my Android projects.

But after many research, I only found solutions with Git on Windows.

When I try to : VCS -> Checkout from Version Control
[image]
Edit : Even if I click on "Test" with a non existing folder, Android Studio studio says "Successful"

And when I try to : VCS -> Import into Version Control
[image]
Edit : Only local...

Could you please tell me if It works only with local Git on Windows or does it exists a way to use Git with my Raspberry?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: What is the issue? Is your ssh URL not working?

Comment: Even if I click on "Test" with a non existing folder or a wrong path, Android Studio studio says "Successful" ... SSH works with Putty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37159115/6309), make sure you have generated openssh (not putty) public/private SSH keys in `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh` (`id_rsa`/`id_rsa.pub`)

And by sure your public key is in ~pi/.ssh/authorizeid_keys

Finally, make sure `ssh -T pi@my.rasp.pi.address` works.

Then you can use your ssh URL:

```
ssh://pi@my.rasp.pi.address/home/pi/folder
```