# remove "remember password" when pushing android studio

Tags: git, android-studio, push

I set my ssh key a password. And whenever I do push or pull it asks me for that password, even in android studio. By mistake I press the "save password" in android studio and I can't enter the password anymore.

Is there any way to delete that? Or make android studio forget the password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check first, as [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54863482/6309), what kind of SSH client your Android Studio is using: internal or system?

Switch to system, and check if your have an ssh-agent running: you can [clear its content](https://superuser.com/a/271673/141).
That should force Android Studio to ask for your private key passphrase again.

Answer (score 0):

Although the question title doesn't specifically mention SSH, though the body of question does, I came to this question looking for non SSH password removal, so perhaps this'll be helpful for both parties.

For Gitlab (& I assume Git) if you tick the remember box when entering your password for Android Studio Dolphin 2021.3.1 and you don't want it to be stored subsequently goto:

**Settings** > **Appearance & Behaviour** > **System Settings** > **Passwords** and then click the *Do not save, forget passwords after restart* button.

[image]

You then have to close and restart Android Studio, but then your password will be 'forgotten'
Obviously unclick the afore-mentioned button to have the behaviour reversed